# Ray Wenderlich's A* path finding tutorial

Tags: tiles, path-finding, a-star, multi-level

I am a huge fan of Ray Wenderlich's tutorials and if you haven't seen them check them out. I am developing a game using his A* pathfinding game.  I love the way you interact however I do not know how to make this multi-level. I have developed more levels and saved them in the correct .TMX format however I can not understand how to link this into Xcode.

Thank you in advanced.